Snowflake - Split column value into multiple columns
Had to extract data from stage table, where the data is in single column with comma as delimiter.
Data AS IS
"pBKey, pBIdentifier, pBDateTime, Store, Description, DeptComm, provider, OrderReferenceNumber,,,,"
"XY-XYX-1234", "RULE-XYZ-XYZ",20240401, "TWXY", , , , "XYZXWENZ"
enter image description here
Output TO BE
enter image description here
Tried a combination of SPLIT_TO_TABLE and Pivot, but results are not as expected.
SQL:
DECLARE 
  col_list STRING DEFAULT (
    SELECT CONCAT('(',LISTAGG(VALUE_COL, ','),')) ORDER BY 1') AS RESULTSTRING FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT VALUE_COL FROM CSV_TEST ORDER BY 1) AS TMP);
   SQL_TO_EXECUTE STRING;
   RS RESULTSET;
BEGIN
  SQL_TO_EXECUTE := $$ 
SELECT *  FROM
(  
  SELECT SEQ as ID, TRIM(F1.VALUE) AS COLNAME, INDEX AS VALUE_COL
    FROM DATA_LOCATION S
    , LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(AS_VARCHAR(S.MESSAGE), ',') F1   
)SRC
PIVOT(
      MIN(COLNAME) FOR VALUE_COL IN $$ || col_list ; 
    RS := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_TO_EXECUTE);
  RETURN TABLE(RS);
END;


RESULT:
enter image description here
Need to remove Header column and make 2nd row as header.
How to get the expected result? Any help would be much appreciated.
enter image description here

Hi, please don’t link to images (as no-one can copy your data to try out a solution). Add all relevant information to your question as editable text, appropriately formatted

yes please add sample data in your question itself.

if the number of columns are fixed you can use Strtok_To_Array as follows
select fld1[0] pBKey , fld1[1] as pBDateTime, fld1[2] as Store,
fld1[3] as Description from(
SELECT STRTOK_TO_ARRAY('XY-XYX-1234, RULE-XYZ-XYZ,20240401, TWXY', ',') fld1
);



Thanks Himanshu, It's close to my expectations. However, I have around 385 columns to be separated. Is there a dynamic way to get the columns renamed.

If this is a one time activity then you use Excel to generate the list of Column and column alias.
